# How can I take photo multiple times using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am using a react-native-image-crop-picker to choose multiple images and taking a photo using a native camera of the device. This code works for choosing multiple photos:

```
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
    multiple: true,
  }).then(images => {
    this.saveImages(images);
  });
```

Now I want to take photo multiple times. I have the following code:

```
  ImagePicker.openCamera({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        multiple: true,
      }).then(images => {
       saveImages(images);
      });
```

But it takes photo only one time. It has two button after taking photo "Повтор" (Repeat) and OK: 
[image: photo]

I can take multiple photos by clicking "Повтор" (Repeat) button. But after clicking OK

```
.then(images => {
       saveImages(images);
      });
```

it takes the last picture. How can I take multiple photos using `ImagePicker.openPicker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the cropper doesn't support taking multiple photos while in camera mode. https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1374